NextJS 14 client route caching for 30 seconds and unable to override
I have an edit page route where the data for the form is fetched on the server and then passed down to the client form component.
I navigate to this page using Next Link component, I make a change to the data in the form, navigate back to the data grid where the Next Link is and navigate back to the form and a cached page is returned with the now stale data if I do so within 30 seconds. After 30 seconds the page is requested afresh and I get fresh data.
In my top level server page.tsx I have export const revalidate = 0, in my middleware I am setting the headers to 'Cache-Control', 'no-store' for EVERY route. I have even tried invalidating the route via an APUI call when the data is mutated using revalidatePath and replaced the Next Link with a router.replace as a means of navigating, but still the 30 second cache.
I feel my design, with the form data being fetched on the server, is reasonable, but how can I ensure that this route is never cached on the client?

You're looking for staleTimes
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        staleTimes: {
            dynamic: 1, //1 second 
            static: 60 //prefetching
        }
    }
}

